# Using Python and ctypes to pass a variable length string inside a structure to c function (generated by Matlab Coder)

Tags: python, matlab, char, structure, ctypes

I am trying to pass a variable size string inside a structure from Python into C code (or rather into a DLL/SO). The C-code is generated by Matlab Coder, so I am fairly limited to changing the C-code (although some tweaks can be made in Matlab to change the output).

I use ctypes in Python to creating structures with various elements and that works, and so does passing variables with strings of varying length. But, I can't get a varying length string inside a structure to work.

Passing a string works well when create a string input in Matlab the generated C-code. I pass the string via ctypes into the C type definitions as follows:

Matlab generated C-code:

```
/* Function Declarations */
extern double test_string_func(const char apa_vl_data[],
                               const int apa_vl_size[2]);
```

Python:

```
str2_in = "hyja"

bb = ct.c_char_p(str2_in.encode('utf-8'))
bb_sz = np.array([1, len(str2_in)]).astype(dtype=int)
bb_sz_p = bb_sz.ctypes.data
```

Initialise and make the call:

```
libC.test_string_func.argtypes = [ct.c_char_p, np.ctypeslib.ndpointer()]
dbl_out = libC.test_string_func(bb, bb_sz)
```

BUT, when I create a struct in Matlab (C and Python) I can't get the call to work:

C-code structure definitions:

```
/* Type Definitions */
#ifndef struct_emxArray_char_T_1x10
#define struct_emxArray_char_T_1x10
struct emxArray_char_T_1x10 {
  char data[10];
  int size[2];
};
#endif /* struct_emxArray_char_T_1x10 */
#ifndef typedef_emxArray_char_T_1x10
#define typedef_emxArray_char_T_1x10
typedef struct emxArray_char_T_1x10 emxArray_char_T_1x10;
#endif /* typedef_emxArray_char_T_1x10 */

#ifndef typedef_struct0_T
#define typedef_struct0_T
typedef struct {
  double val;
  emxArray_char_T_1x10 str;
} struct0_T;
#endif /* typedef_struct0_T */
```

from the header file:

```
extern double test_string_func(const struct0_T *apa_struct);
```

One approach of many that I have tried in Python:

```
class emxArray_char_T_1x10(ct.Structure):
    """ creates a struct to match emxArray_char_T_1x10

     C-code from Matlab:
     /* Type Definitions */
        #ifndef struct_emxArray_char_T_1x10
        #define struct_emxArray_char_T_1x10
        struct emxArray_char_T_1x10 {
        char data[10];
        int size[2];
        }; """

    _fields_ = [('data', ct.c_char_p),
                ('size', ct.POINTER(ct.c_int))]


class testInStruct(ct.Structure):
    """creates a struct to match struct in C file

    C-code from Matlab:
    /* Type Definitions */
        typedef struct {
        double val;
        emxArray_char_T_1x10 str;
        } struct0_T;
    """

    _fields_ = [
        ("struct_input_val", ct.c_double),
        ("struct_input_str", emxArray_char_T_1x10),
    ]


# initialise struct data
input_string = "INPUT!!"

input_str = emxArray_char_T_1x10()
input_str.data = ct.c_char_p(input_string.encode('utf-8'))

# Pass a list of int
L = [1, len(input_string)]
arr = (ct.c_int * len(L))()
arr[:] = L
input_str.size = arr

sd = testInStruct()
sd.struct_input_val = 2.1
sd.struct_input_str = input_str

libC.test_string_func.argtypes = [ct.POINTER(testInStruct)]
dbl_out = libC.test_string_func(sd)
```

I have managed to make fairly complex structures work, with varying types and arrays as input. But the cause of the error passing a string in a struct eludes me.

**Update: forgot to say that the C code runs when called in Python, but produce an incorrect length of the string inside the C-code and exit code when I try to "fprinf" the passed string inside the C-code.**

Any idea what I might do wrong?

By the way, this is the standard format for structures with variable length variables, and those are easily dealt with:

```
struct emxArray_real_T
{
  double *data;
  int *size;
  int allocatedSize;
  int numDimensions;
  boolean_T canFreeData;
};
```

Comment: As an alternative to using ctypes, you could also consider generating a Python wrapper using something like SWIG. In case they're helpful, here are some examples we made doing that with MATLAB Coder https://github.com/mathworks/coder-swig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C struct

```c
struct emxArray_char_T_1x10 {
  char data[10];
  int size[2];
};
```

should be matched with Ctypes in Python as

```py
class emxArray_char_T_1x10(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = [('data', ct.c_char * 10),
                ('size', ct.POINTER(ct.c_int))]
```

Note the difference between `char* a` and `char b[10]` in this context. Yes,  `b` can be seen as a pointer to the first element of an array, but the structure contains the actual array, 10 chars, not one pointer to a char.

Comment: @Chris, this helped me to get on the right track you were right on the "ct.c_char * 10" part. This change invoked some consequential modifications that I will show in an update or answer.

Answer (score 2):

The change suggested by Chris Luengo works, but impose some additional modifications to get everything to work. It goes as follows:

The emxArray_char_T_1x10 section should be:

```
class emxArray_char_T_1x10(ct.Structure):
      _fields_ = [('data', ct.c_char * 10),
                  ('size', ct.c_int * 2))]
```

and the "initialise struct data" section should be reworked as follows:

```
# initialise struct data
input_string = "INPUT!!"

input_str = emxArray_char_T_1x10()
arr_1 = bytes(input_string, 'utf-8')

input_str.data = arr_1
```